# ADFV2, VNET, and Linked Services

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I have an ADFv2, ADLS Gen2 and SQL Database all configured on a VNET. I'd like to connect from the data factory to the storage account and SQL database however I get a permission error on the data factory (see below).

I know I can stand up an integration runtime to solve the connectivity however, is there any way to configure the linked service to avoid the Virtual machine and IR config yet?

Thanks

[image: ADF Error]

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Not really @JayGong - are you saying I dont need an IR when connecting ADFV2 to Blob Storage within a VNET?

Comment: I'm saying that adls need to be granted read permission from ADF since your error indicates permission mismatch,you could check it. Surely,IR is needed!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that the error is not related to the IR,to the Permission instead.

You could refer to this link [Service principal authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage#service-principal-authentication) to grant permission for your ADF to accessing ADLS. If ADLS is source, the READ permission is needed at least,i think.

[image]